# Cross platform way to terminate process in Go

Tags: windows, unix, go

So to terminate a process on an Ubuntu machine, I can send a `syscall.SIGTERM` signal to my process, but that won't work on Windows.
To fix it, I've switched to using `syscall.TerminateProcess` but of course that is not supported on Ubuntu. 
Is there a way to terminate a process that would work on both platform or will I need to have separate code for unix and for windows?

Comment: [`os.Process.Kill`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Process.Kill) is cross-platform.

Comment: os.Process.Kill causes the process to exit immediately. So you won't be able to kill its child processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine your operating system at runtime using [runtime.GOOS](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOOS).

As you have to compile the code for the respective platform at some point, you could write OS specific code pretty easily.

All the relevant documentation is available in [Go build](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/).

> If a file's name, after stripping the extension and a possible _test
>   suffix, matches *_GOOS, *_GOARCH, or *_GOOS_GOARCH for
>   any known operating system and architecture values, then the file
>   is considered to have an implicit build constraint requiring those
>   terms.

That basically means e.g. a file named `mypackage_windows.go` will only be included when compiling for windows.